# bash error: ./mac_or_linux.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file - Nested ifs

Tags: bash

I am learning bash.
while doing an exercise I got an error

The ifs script ask for a choice then shows either one of 3 messages. 
The error comes after the choice is selected.

```
#!/bin/bash
#nested ifs. script give user option to choose an OS.
osch=0
echo "1.Mac"
echo "2.Linux"
echo -n "Select your OS choice [1 or 2]? "
read osch
if [ $osch -eq 1 ] ; then
echo "You pick up Mac"
else #### nested if i.e if within if ######
if [ $osch -eq 2 ] ; then
echo "You pick up Linux"
else
echo "You don't like Mac/Linux OS."
fi
```

Error:

```
[root@localhost bash_shell_script]# ./mac_or_linux.sh
1.Mac
2.Linux
Select your OS choice [1 or 2]? 2
./mac_or_linux.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[root@localhost bash_shell_script]#
```

It says error line 19 which does not even exit. Any idea?

really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is always a good place to start. The error is that you are missing a final `fi`.

When that is said, you should know about `elif`:

```
if [ "$osch" -eq 1 ]; then
  do_stuff
elif [ "$osch" -eq 2 ]; then
  do_other_stuff
fi
```

And `case`:

```
case $osch in
  1) do_stuff ;;
  2) do_other_stuff ;;
  *) echo "osch doesn't contain 1 nor 2" >&2 ;;
esac
```

Comment: That's exactly what happened. Thank you very much for your response! It's executing perfectly now!